# Two text alignments in one paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have to write a paragraph, such that it should look like

```
1st line: align:center
2nd line: align:left
3rd line: align:center
4th line: align:left
```

it should go like this.

How can i do it using CSS.

Comment: You can style the `p::first-line` separately, but that's the only line that CSS is capable of styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `nth-child(even)` selector

```
p:nth-child(even) {
    text-align:center
}
```

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkana/sWd7Q/)

EDIT: Bartdude is right. This solution only works if you separate each paragraph.

Comment: in that case, if i have to write 100 lines , i should use 100 paragraphs ??

Comment: Yes. If that's a problem, you should look into server-side scripting like PHP or Ruby. Also, if you editor is good, you shouldn't need to worry about writing an extra line. Take a look at Zen Coding and see if there is support for your text editor.

Comment: @R.Reddy But, if you do not separate the lines the output result might be like "1st line: align:center 2nd line: align:left 3rd line: align:center 4th line: align:left" << all "inline". Do you use `<pre>` tag or `<br>` or something to separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 1 block element containing each different line of your text. If you only have a p tag with all the text, it's not possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class-attribute...

example:

```
<p class="centerAlign">1st line: align:center</p>
<p class="leftAlign">2nd line: align:left</p>
<p class="centerAlign">3rd line: align:center</p>
<p class="leftAlign">4th line: align:left</p>
```

The rules in your css-file should look like that:

```
p.centerAlign {....}
p.leftAlign {....}
```

Comment: if i have 100 lines, i have to write this 100 times ??

Comment: what kind of text do you have? is it a list?

Comment: No. it's just a paragraph with some lines.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CSS lacks the ability of selecting lines, apart from the `:first-line` pseudo selector. So, unfortunately you won't be seeing a pure CSS solution to this problem anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by simply formatting each

tag for each new line.

Change the CSS as appropriate.

Something like this might work:

Use `<p class="align_____">x line: align:______</p>`